# criar trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, trigger

Tenho duas tabelas: a tabela pedidos e a tabela logs. Os usuarios podem interagir com o tabela pedidos, atarvés de um script php que roda uma query update e atualiza a coluna status.
Preciso criar um trigger que, quando rodar esse query update, salve a alteração na tabela log.

Usei essa trigger, mas agora não atualiza nem a tabela pedido, nem a tabela log:

```
        DELIMITER $$
        CREATE TRIGGER salva_status 
        BEFORE UPDATE ON pedidos
        FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO logs
        SET acao = 'update',
        nPedido = OLD.nPedido,
        status = OLD.status,
        modificadoem = NOW(); END$$
        DELIMITER ;
```

Essas são as query para criação da table:

Essa table é a que armazena as infos dos pedidos

```
         CREATE TABLE `localhost`.`pedidos` ( `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `emissaoPed` INT NOT NULL , 
        `nPed` INT NOT NULL , 
        `NrPedido` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
         `nomeAbrev` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL , 
        `vlr` FLOAT NOT NULL , 
        `status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
        UNIQUE (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

E essa é a tabela que vai armazenar os logs:

```
        CREATE TABLE `root`.`logs` ( 
        `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , 
        `NrPedido` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
        `antigoStatus` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
        `novoStatus` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL ,
         `modificadoem` DATE NOT NULL , 
        `vlr` FLOAT NOT NULL , 
        `status` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL , 
        UNIQUE (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Tente colocar `AFTER UPDATE ON pedidos` veja se altera algo

Comment: Alterei a query e sem efeito :/

Comment: Mas deixa eu te perguntar, quando você quer inserir um registro em uma tabela através de uma Trigger, tu não precisa usar o comando de `insert` de acordo com esse link https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/triggers/after_update.php ???

Comment: Cara Tente alterar esse insert.... INSERT INTO logs(acao,nPedido,Status) VALUES ('update',OLD.nPedido, OLD.status, NOW());

Comment: manda os creates tables que eu faço a trigger

Comment: Não `INSERT INTO logs SET...` é `INSERT INTO logs VALUES` ou `INSERT INTO logs (acao, nPedido, status, modificagem) VALUES (...)`

Comment: Então pessoal, coloquei a query que usei para criar as tabelas para ficar mais claro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente trocar o INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO logs
        SET acao = 'update',
        nPedido = OLD.nPedido,
        status = OLD.status,
        modificadoem = NOW();
```

para

```
 INSERT INTO logs
          (acao, nPedido, status, modificagem)
        VALUES
          ('update', OLD.nPedido, OLD.status, NOW());
```

Comment: era bem isso que eu estava sugerindo nos comentários +1

Comment: Então R.Santos, não funcionou, mas coloquei a query que usei para criar as tabelas, acho que fui em quem comeu bola, rs

Comment: CORRIGINDO: a query funcionou, os termos na minha tabela que não estavam bem definidos